# Please help me with my joomla template

Tags: joomla, background-image, joomla-template

I'm currently using this [template](http://www.yootheme.com/demo/themes/joomla/2010/expo/index.php) in my joomla site and I dont know why i can't see the background image. i tried with internet explorer , firefox and chrome and I tried to edit the template style sheet but I still cant see the background image, what can I do?

Comment: Which background image? A link to the site you are having problems with would be helpful. No way to see what is wrong with your site by looking at another site that works.

Answer (score 0):

Without providing any other info or a direct link i can't help you.

Anyway try to change permission on template folder to 775.
If you can't access directly via ftp, install a component like ninjaxplorer (it's free)
and go on templates/yt_expo and change permission on folder/subfolder and files.